# * operator in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a following function in excel which works as expected:

```
=FILTER(Database!A2:C1947,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G3,Database!A2:A1947)*SEARCH(G4,Database!A2:A1947)),"Not found")
```

In this function, I have strings from A2 to C1947. out of the entire table,  I want to show only those rows which contain strings written in G3 and G4. So basically the filter function takes key1 from G3 and key2 from G4. and filter out rows that contain strings from G3 and G4.

Example:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row1 | screw 5 mm helix | quantity 77 |
| Row2 | screw 5 mm | quantity 10 |
| Row3 | screw 10 mm helix | quantity 98 |
| Row4 | nut 3 mm | quantity 96 |

then when I enter "screw" in G3 and "helix" in G4, I get following in excel:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Row1 | screw 5 mm helix | quantity 77 |
| Row3 | screw 10 mm helix | quantity 98 |

However when I write the same function in VBA, it gives error as "Run time error 13, type mismatch" following is my excel VBA code:

```
Dim Res As Variant
With Application
    Res = .Filter(Sheets("Database").Range("A2:C1947"), .IsNumber(.Search(Sheets("Tool").Range("G3"), Sheets("Database").Range("A2:A1947")) * .Search(Sheets("Tool").Range("G4"), Sheets("Database").Range("A2:A1947"))), "Not found")
End With
```

Where is my mistake? Need an expert advice.

Comment: The way you are using * is as a multiplication, not as a wildcard.

Comment: Then what should be done? If I remove  * .Search(Sheets("Tool").Range("G4"), Sheets("Database").Range("A2:A1947") then it works and there is no error

Comment: Can you show some example data and explain what you expect `SEARCH(G3,Database!A2:A1947)` to do? Because that would be the same as  `SEARCH(G3,Database!A3)`. Search does give as result the position of an occurence within a string. So I don't get what you are trying to do with that formula. Please show a [mcve] with example input/output data.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, I have modified the question so that, you can get better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few mistakes I picked up here:

- You forgot the `ISNUMBER()` function in front of your 2nd criteria in the 2nd parameter of your `FILTER()`.
- In Excel you should write the double criteria filter as `(criteria1)*(criteria2)`, therefore you forgot the outer paranthesis.
- What does work for Excel, does not always work in VBA, meaning both the criteria would have given a 2D-array back. If anything you should have used `TRANSPOSE()` in front of them both making it look like:

  ```
  Res = .Filter(Sheets("Database").Range("A2:C1947"), (.Transpose(.IsNumber(.Search(Sheets("Tool").Range("G3"), Sheets("Database").Range("A2:A1947"))))) * (.Transpose(.IsNumber(.Search(Sheets("Tool").Range("G4"), Sheets("Database").Range("C2:C1947"))))), "Not found")
  ```

However, you'll find this still doesn't work since VBA won't be able to just multiply the first critera's 1D-array with the 2nd one. In short ***`1D-array * 1D-array`* does not work** in VBA. Therefor you should use `Application.Evaluate` to mimic the `FILTER()` with the double-criteria:

```
Res = .Evaluate("=FILTER(Database!A2:C1947, (ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Tool!G3, Database!A2:A1947)))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Tool!G4, Database!C2:C1947))), ""Not found"")")
```